# Given a set of coins find number of way to get a sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation

What is the way to solve the following kinds of problem:

Give coins of 2, 4, 6 find a number of ways to get n as a sum.

Say n = 6

We can get n = 6 answer is 4.

> > [2, 2, 2],  [2, 4], [4, 2]
> >     , [6]

For a small number, I can solve it simple factorization but for large numbers this approach is not feasible.

Comment: Are you sure you want 2+4 and 4+2 to count as different solutions?  That is a valid thing to count but in this context they feel like the same arrangement of coins.

Comment: For the general problem (*assuming $2+4$ really is considered differently than $4+2$*), you might consider using generating functions and computer assistance.  The number of ways in your problem being the coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (x^2+x^4+x^6)^k$, which you can [see is $4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D1+to+3+of+%28x%5E2%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E6%29%5Ek).  For the more general problem, just replace the terms in the parentheses by $x$'s raised to the various powers of available coins.

Comment: On the other hand, if $2+4$ is considered to be the *same* as $4+2$, and all we cared about was the quantity of each type of coin and not the order in which the coins appeared, consider instead the generating function $(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\dots)(1+x^4+x^8+\dots)(1+x^6+x^{12}+\dots)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JMoravitz's comment is correct: the result can be obtained by looking at a particular coefficient in the generating function.

Alternatively, since the order in which the coins were used is important in your problem, you can solve the homogeneous recurrence $f(n) = f(n-2) + f(n-4) + f(n-6)$ with initial conditions $f(0)=1$ and $f(k)=0$ for $k<0$.

```
n   f(n)
02  1
04  2
06  4
08  7
10  13
12  24
14  44
16  81
18  149
20  274
22  504
24  927
26  1705
28  3136
30  5768
32  10609
34  19513
36  35890
38  66012
40  121415
42  223317
44  410744
46  755476
48  1389537
50  2555757
```

Here is the Python code I used to make the table above.

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(n):
    if n == 0: return 1
    if n  < 0: return 0
    return f(n-2) + f(n-4) + f(n-6)
```

Comment: Answer verified. (+1)

Comment: $f(2n)$ is the $n$th Tribonacci number ([OEIS A000073](https://oeis.org/A000073)).

Comment: @RobPratt: Nice. Your transformation yields a linear homogeneous recurrence  of low order (as you said, the Tribonacci recurrence), which you can solve to obtain an expression of the form $c_1 r_1^n + c_2 r_2^n + c_3 r_3^n$ for OP's question. [The solution is here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html).

Answer (score 4):

Here  we calculate the  number $a_n$ of ways to represent *even* $n$ using generating functions. It  is  convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> Since the coins $\{2,4,6\}$ are multiples of $2$, we set $n=2N$  and  obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a_n}&=[x^{2N}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(x^2+x^4+x^6\right)^k\\
> &=[x^{2N}]\sum_{k=0}^Nx^{2k}\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^N[x^{2N-2k}]\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\left(x^2+x^4\right)^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^N[x^{2k}]\sum_{j=0}^{N-k}\binom{N-k}{j}x^{2j}\left(1+x^2\right)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{N-k,k\}}\binom{N-k}{j}[x^{2k-2j}]\left(1+x^2\right)^j\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{N-k,k\}}\binom{N-k}{j}\binom{j}{k-j}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
> resulting in
> \begin{align*}
> (a_{2N})_{N\geq 1}=(1,2,4,7,13,24,44,81,149,274,504,\ldots)
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the answer from @parsiad.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we  factor out $x^{2k}$.
- In (2) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$  and apply  the binomial theorem  to  $(1+(x^2+x^4))^k$. We also set the upper limit of the outer sum to $N$ since other terms do not contribute to $[x^{2N-2k}]$.
- In (3)  we  change  the order of summation $k\to  N-k$.
- In  (4) we  apply  the rule  $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$  again by also setting the upper limit of the inner sum accordingly.
- In (5) we select the coeffient of $x^{2k-2j}$.